# Parse Content of Blogger Admin Page

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blogger

(I'm searching solutions to do this for hours with no success!)

It is possible to parse the below blogger link?

https://draft.blogger.com/manage-followers.g?blogID=my_blog_id

How do i sign-in to google account and request that html content?

I intend to use GAE(python) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Blogger API documetation](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/users/get) you can only read information about users, not change (manage) it.  You should try to do it with the [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/), taking care to meet blogger.com's [authentication requirements](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#auth), otherwise your AppEngine client code will be denied access.